# What is the equivalent function in sqlite for find_in_set(value,set) in MySQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

The example below is w.r.t MySQL.
For eg: test1 is as follows

```
+----+------------------------+
| id | name                   |
+----+------------------------+
|  2 | 1,2                    |
| 33 | 2,44,33,5              |
|  1 | 11,4,55                |
| 12 | 11,111,122,551,112,221 |
+----+------------------------+
```

select * 
from `test1` 
where find_in_set('122',name)

will o/p the following:

```
+----+------------------------+
| id | name                   |
+----+------------------------+
| 12 | 11,111,122,551,112,221 |
+----+------------------------+
```

In Sql Lite, using like it would be:

```
select * 
from `test1` 
where name like '%,122,%'
or name like '122,%'
or name like '%,122'
or name = '122'
```

> A case:

My value is 551,122. In this case,as value is returned from appln we can split the value column & write the query as

```
(',' || column_name || ',') LIKE '%,551,%' or
(',' || column_name || ',') LIKE '%,122,%'
```

any best idea to handle this ?

I wanna avoid like. So any other idea?

Comment: You could use `LIKE`:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979813/alternative-to-find-in-set-in-sqlite/6980615#6980615

Comment: I don't understand your comment?

Comment: I don't think what you want to do can be done in pure SQLite, without changing your schema.  There may be third-party SQLite add-ons that will do what you want with an array datatype, or maybe you could write your own function to do what you want.

Comment: @Flimzy: SQLite doesn't support [arrays](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: @muistooshort: Oh really?  I coulda sworn I'd seen reference to that somewhere... maybe as an add-on?  Or maybe I dreamt it.

Comment: Datatype of 'name' is string. @John sorry. I wanna avoid like but if there is no better solution, I will go for it.

Comment: Whoever added `find_in_set` to MySQL should be given a stern talking to.

Comment: Iam going for stackoverflow.com/questions/6979813/… solution as I dont require the index

Comment: I cannot go for the solution becoz of another forgotten case if my value is not just 551,122. How will we handle this? We can split & loop over & use individually for 122 & 551 separately

Answer (score 6):

My first idea is that you shouldn't store CSV data in a column in a relational database, you should use a separate association table.

You can make this work with LIKE though. Your comment indicates that you see the three cases but there are actually four:

```
select *
from test1
where name like '122,%'
   or name like '%,122'
   or name like '%,122,%'
   or name    = '122'     /* You forgot about this degenerate case */
```

An index can be used for the last case and possibly for the first but the middle two will probably be table scans. You can simplify the query if you force your data to always have the leading and trailing commas:

```
+----+--------------------------+
| id | name                     |
+----+--------------------------+
|  2 | ,1,2,                    |
| 33 | ,2,44,33,5,              |
|  1 | ,11,4,55,                |
| 12 | ,11,111,122,551,112,221, |
+----+--------------------------+
```

Then you can use just one LIKE (which won't use an index):

```
select *
from test1
where name like '%,122,%'
```

But you really should use an association table so that you could use `where name = 122` and join to other tables for the rest.

Comment: +1 `shouldn't store CSV data in a column in a relational database` why do you want to save space in table by storing as CSV?

Comment: You also shouldn't name a CSV column "name"... Unless someone's/something's name is actually "1,2".  Maybe it's a database of cybernetic creatures from Star Trek.

Comment: @mu is too short Rather than forcing  your data to always have the leading and trailing commas you can go thru John Weldon link & use (',' || column_name || ',') LIKE '%,value,%' & thanks for the forgotten case but thats handled by the mentioned solution

Comment: @Angelin: That's an interesting approach but you should still fix your schema and use an association table.

Comment: @mu is too short: ya but I cannot cahnge the schema as its the third party database

Comment: @Angelin: You can't copy the data to an association table and use that instead?

Comment: Ok can give it a try but as last priority as looking for some string functions that can handle it or built as customize function as find_in_set() available in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to go with the tactic mentioned by John Weldon,

So,

```
select *
from test1
where (',' || column_name || ',') LIKE '%,122,%' //any value
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979813/alternative-to-find-in-set-in-sqlite/6980615#6980615)

Answer (score 0):

Create a function

```
public class ConnectionOpenHandler extends Interceptor{
  private static final long serialVersionUID=1;
  private String nameConnection;
  private String jdbcUrl;

  public void handler(Handler handler) throws Exception{
    Context context=(Context)handler.getProperty("context");
    SessionContext sessionContext=(SessionContext)context;

    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    handler.setProperty(nameConnection,connection);
    sessionContext.getProtectedContext().setProperty(nameConnection,connection);

    Function.create(connection,"find_in_set",new FindInSet());
  }
  private class FindInSet extends Function{
    protected void xFunc() throws SQLException{
      String row=this.value_text(0);
      String values=this.value_text(1);

      if(values==null){
        result(0);
        return;
      }

      boolean ok=Arrays.asList(values.split("\\,")).contains(row);
      result(ok?1:0);
    }
  }
}
```