# SQLite: Matching a column containig a single string to another column containing comma-separated values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have table A where acolumn contains a comma-separated string like this:

```
table A:
+--------------+
|     comsep   |
+--------------+
|  "a,d,g,h"   |
|      "c"     |
|     "f,i"    |
+--------------+
```

and a table B where a column references one of the values within the comma-separated string from table A, like this:

```
table B:
+-----+------+
| id  | ref  |
+------------+
| 1  |  "a"  |
| 2  |  "d"  |
| 3  |  "c"  |
| 4  |  "u"  |
| 5  | null  |
+------------+
```

How can I select those values from table B where the value in the `ref`-column appears in the `comsep`-column of table A.
For the above example the output I want would be:

```
+-----+------+
| id  | ref  |
+------------+
| 1  |  "a"  |
| 2  |  "d"  |
| 3  |  "c"  |
+------------+
```

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926020/what-is-the-equivalent-function-in-sqlite-for-find-in-setvalue-set-in-mysql

Comment: @outis yes, thank you